# How can I embed a large string in a .NET application in a Linux dev environment

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET 6 web application and I'd like to embed a large static string in it. The string is roughly 350 kB large. The usual answer especially for .NET Framework would be a resource file, but I'm developing on Linux and therefore can't easily use Windows binaries like resgen.exe or Visual Studio. There are certainly workaround possible here, but I hesitate to try and add a mechanism here to the build that isn't designed around being used on Linux.

So I would strongly prefer a method that works on Linux and with the command line `dotnet` tool alone, not requiring e.g. Visual Studio.

The string is also large enough that I'm not sure it is safe to add this simply as a string literal in a `.cs` file. I don't want to later find out that some tools or IDE features break or get incredibly slow because they try to do something with that large blob.

What would be a safe and convenient way to embed such a large string in a .NET executable when using Linux as a development environment?

Comment: attach it as a separate file - embedded resource?

Comment: @YehorAndrosov everything I found on that requires using a Windows binary like resgen.exe or Visual Studio. So I'd have to add a Windows-only step to the development that right now is entirely on Linux.

Comment: Why do you need resgen.exe?  Save it in a file, add as an EmbeddedResource in the csproj, and use Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream() to read it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643620/read-a-resourse-file-using-assembly-getmanifestresourcestream-method-using-c-sha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a Resourse file using Assembly GetManifestResourceStream method using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643620/read-a-resourse-file-using-assembly-getmanifestresourcestream-method-using-c-sha)

Comment: @Tarazed the linked question and answers use Visual Studio and don't explain how to actually embed the string as a resource without using Windows Tools.

Comment: Open the csproj file and add an ``<ItemGroup>`` entry ``<EmbeddedResource Include="relative path"/>``

Comment: Well, that explains how to do it without VS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762368/embedded-resource-in-net-core-libraries